# Excel formula to increment every third row by 1

Tags: excel-2010

I want to write a formula that will increment every third row by one while filling the previous rows by the previous number incremented.

Ex.
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3

Thank you for your help,
Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer divide of rownumber - row on which we start by 3, plus 1, or

```
=QUOTIENT(ROW()-1;3)+1
```